# Server 2019 - restrict port 3389

Tags: windows-firewall, windows-server-2019

There seem to be plenty of explanations on how to restrict port 3389 to certain IP addresses - open Firewall and the 3389 rule. Add required IP addresses to Remote IP addresses under the scope tab and save.. After doing this and testing it the port is still open (tested with PortCheckers.com) There are no other, conflicting or otherwise, rules for 3389 - baffled. What have I missed?

[image: Firewall]

======================== UPDATE ===================

It started working - really odd because normally with port 3389 as soon as you click 'Apply' you lose connection and then it reconnects (unless of course you forgot to add your own IP address). This time nothing happened, but now everything is working - Windows voodoo :-)

Comment: hows about pictures?

Comment: Pic added as requested

Comment: Unless you completely disable that port, it remains opened. The rule you configured does limit which remote IP addresses are allowed to connect to it, but it won't disable the port. The actual common practice is to move the service to another port (such as 56xxx), so that you can completely disable 3389.

Comment: You haven't closed the port, you are just restricting what machines are allowed to connect on that port. Be aware, IP address can be spoofed.